# Running keychaindump.c from GitHub but there are deprecated variables

Tags: xcode, xcode4, github, deprecated

I am running the Keychaindump script from GutHub on my computer using xcode4 and im getting some errors upon building and running the script.

DES_set_key is deprecated

How can I get rid of this error?

Thanks

The script can be found here

https://github.com/juuso/keychaindump/blob/master/keychaindump.c

Comment: It would be good, if you'll attach a link to this script

Comment: sorry, i have attached the link

Answer (score 0):

@Aleister Cooper: you have to attach 2 library: libcrypto.dylib and libssl.dylib. Try it.